# In Android, how do I download the HTML of a webpage?

Tags: java, html, android, curl

In Python, I use a class called "urllib".
I'd just  like a simple function where I can download the HTML of a webpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [java.net.URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html)

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
```